# In PDDL, how can I access time since *start* as a variable?

Tags: pddl

I know that in durative effects, I can compute based on #t, which is some flavor of elapsed time.  But from the examples I see, it seems to be more like the duration of the effect itself: for instance, boil water, and heat it by a certain amount for the time it boils.  Whereas, I want to have a cost that factors in total elapsed time since the start of the entire plan.  Is that a different variable?

I tried `(increase (total-cost) (* #t (num-not-yet-fixed ?group)))` Where the num-not-yet-fixed goes down over time, and the idea is to increase the cost by a higher value if more things being "fixed" are fixed later rather than earlier.  But (a) popf rejected the use of #t here, it seems, and (b) it seems like even if it worked, it would be for the fixed duration of the durative effect, and not since the start of execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any chance you can create a new function, say `(now)`, that starts at 0, is added to linearly over time via a full-plan envelope action, and then used by the other actions to refer to things?

Something like this...

```
(:durative-action measure-time
 :precondition (begin)
 :effect (and
   (at start (going))
   (at start (not (begin)))
   (at end (not (going)))
   (increase (now) #t)
 )

; all other actions have a condition (over all (going))

; any action that needs to refer to the current time in the plan can use the function (now)
```

...and the init would have:

```
; used so that the measure-time happens only once
(begin)

; a function to measure the current time and use in an action
(= (now) 0)
```

...and the goal should be modified to also include `(not (going))`

Comment: First I guess I'd have to understand a "full-plan envelope action" :).  But this means there really isn't the idea of a wall clock available to the actions?  Quite surprising!

Comment: Google doesn't know that phrase, so I'm not exactly sure how it would work.  I could add it in each other function, but then I'd double count if multiple functions are invoked in parallel.   Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I'll add that if I whittle down the phrase to simply _envelope_ I do find hits, but mostly more theoretical stuff, not actual PDDL examples so far.  So I still don't know how to use this suggestion.  (As you can probably tell, I'm new to this area.)  I appreciate all the feedback!

Comment: Sorry about that. Just meant that you have a single new action that encompasses every other action (using a new fluent like `(going)` to do this). That one new action is effectively marking the passage of time, and the only thing that changes the `(now)` value.

Comment: I still don't quite see how it counts elapsed time of the form of the durations of actions, rather than the total number of tasks executed.   So yeah, I could have every action increment a count, and it would be a rough idea of progress, but when many things can happen in parallel, or take a long time, it wouldn't really reflect time.

Comment: The actions don't increment the value. Only the mega action does. It should increment it as a (linear) function of time. Then all the other actions just need to fit within it. I.e., start & end entirely during the mega-action. All of the other actions could read from it, but just not write to it.

Comment: I'm afraid I still don't see how it works.  Is there a public example of this?

Comment: None immediately come to mind. Just updated the response to show the example.

Comment: Thanks again, @haz.  I've tried using this and am getting syntax errors (with no further info and nothing obviously amiss), including after I changed "precondition" to "condition (at start..."  Increasing verbosity doesn't tell me what it doesn't like.

Comment: So an update on this.  I'm not sure exactly why popf was balking.  It seems like it didn't like the missing duration in the durative action.  I tried running it with an explicit duration, and it executes, but it just keeps running for hours.  With some verbose debugging I got:

```
.........................d...............................d...............................d...............................d...............................d...............
```

indefinitely.  Tried trimming my problem but without any effect, it still blows up.  From the envelope I assume?

Comment: I reran without the detailed debugging, and came back to it hours later with it being killed.  I suppose it had a memory leak or something.

`Initial heuristic = 37.000
b (36.000 | 1.000)b (35.000 | 1.001)b (34.000 | 1.001)b (33.000 | 1.001)b (32.000 | 1.001)b ...22.008)b (6.000 | 22.008)b (5.000 | 27.007)b (4.000 | 27.008)b (3.000 | 27.008)b (2.000 | 27.008)b (1.000 | 27.008)
Resorting to best-first search
b (36.000 | 1.000)b (35.000 | 1.001)b (34.000 | 1.001)b (33.000 | 1.001)b (32.000 | 1.001)b ... 
| 27.007)b (3.000 | 27.008)b (2.000 | 27.008)b (1.000 | 27.008)Killed`

Comment: Maybe run with optic using `-T` (forces it to search in a total ordering rather than partial -- sometimes useful)

Comment: I was so hoping that would do it, but it's been running for close to an hour, and grown to close to 100GB, without producing a result.

Comment: I'm still very confused why it doesn't allow the durative action without a duration.  You suggested a version without it, and I tried that at length, always hitting syntax errors and such.  When I added duration=1, it ran, but blew up.  Certainly making the overall duration be just 1 when individual steps take longer would be problematic ... so I tried increasing the envelope to a fixed duration of 100 (longer than any of the steps would cumulatively take).  It now makes more progress but prints a boatload of "(G)" and seems to come up with a worse plan than before.  LOL.

Comment: Another update: I've noticed that popf seems to run OK with my latest version, whereas optic hangs, with or without the `-T` flag or other ones I've tried.  But it's progress...

Comment: I probably declared victory a bit early there. The "latest version" was a slimmed down problem with one group of thingies that could only be selected a smaller number at a time.  But if I use the original problem, with three groups that each can have some number selected, popf behaves like optic was with the smaller problem, hanging while it blows up.

Comment: I think it always needs that duration spec. Maybe you could get away with saying the duration is just greater than or equal to 0?

Comment: thanks, _progress!_   With that change, I got popf to run with the full set of objects, though optic still blows up with (G) forever. So that's something.

What I don't understand is why it outputs that the total cost is 0.  I have a function (total-cost), which I _increase_ each time the main action is performed, and for which the metric is to minimize that value.  The plan seems reasonable, but I want to be able to play with the formula for `total-cost` and cause it to make different decisions based on how cost is added.  If you have any thoughts (or even how to debug ....

Comment: Actually, hold off on that: while I wasn't seeing it toward the end of the output if I enabled verbose debugging, I see that it is tracking some changes earlier in the processing, which maybe I can sort out.

Comment: Yeah, I don't get it.  If I look at the logs (`-v100`) I see it seeming to adjust total-cost by reasonable values, but then it still says the range is 0,0.  Then at some point it declares the range is 0, X where X is a, I don't know, 200-digit number, which is then shown as 0,inf (infinity).  Neither 0 nor infinity as an upper bound is reasonable.

Comment: Weird...any chance you can get things checked through VAL? It's available on planutils if that's what you happen to be using: `val -l domain.pddl problem.pddl plan.out > out.tex` (and then compile the latex)

Comment: It looks like you meant `val Validate -l ...` -- I was surprised `val --help` failed after `val -t`  but `val help` without hyphens set me straight.  So I did that, and it complained that the plan I fed it didn't satisfy goals.  I looked at what popf said, and it output that it was taking the necessary steps, but it wasn't including the side effects -- so the end goal was never mentioned.  Maybe a different option to popf so that val sees under the covers?

Comment: I even tried popf -v 20 which showed that `at end` it was setting the things val was complaining about, but val still says no goal is satisfied.

Comment: Same with optic?

Comment: For this one, optic just keeps stuttering: `(G)(G)(G)(G)(G)(G)...`  It does produce a plan before that happens, which seems to be the same as POPF.  In any case, val makes the same complaint about not meeting goals.

Comment: I suspect now both solvers can't handle such a thing. I've stripped it down to a fairly minimal example ( http://editor.planning.domains/#read_session=JNYvJV9480 ), and have reached out to the planner authors to see what they say. Will report back here.

Comment: So, it's been a week; I'm still hoping you'll get an answer but I can't say I'm holding my breath.  Is there a different planner that actually handles your example?

Comment: Aye, I think they just went and had another kid, so haven't been responding at all ;). No other planners that I'm aware of -- it's not exactly my sub-field of planning. You can come raise the question in the community slack ( slack.planning.domains ), as there may be some extra eyes over there.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll try that.  

Kids!  They only get in the way.  <ducks> ......